# htaccess - loop on redirection to the same domain

Tags: .htaccess, loops

I want to warm up people around my new project so I want to make a landing page accessible before a given date and then it must redirect to the complete website.

Before the given date :
Every call to anypage of the website (even /) must redirect temporaryly to /promo/index.php

After the same given date :
Every call to /promo/* must redirect to the root of the website /

I began with the first rule like this :

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20180705095200 [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /promo/index.php [R=301,L]
```

=> Before the date : It redirects well the root / to promo/index.php but if I try /Home it doesn't redirects to promo

I also tried :

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20180705095200 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /promo/index.php [R=301,L] # LOOPS
```

=> Before the date : It clearly redirects every URL to /promo/index.php but it seems that it also redirects /promo/index.php itself to itself (it throws me a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).

Then I tried to shut all my other rules for a test and the loop continues to be thrown...

> Edit 2*

Thanks to FoxyFish I now have the following code :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/promo/index.php$ 
RewriteCond %{TIME} <19800705095200 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|gif|png|js|css|ttf|ico|json) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /promo/index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME} >19800705095200 [NC]
RewriteRule /promo/index.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

But the "After" effect (:p) does not work... 
I mean : after the expiration date the /promo/index.php does not redirect to /. It is still accessible.

> Edit 3*

Here is the final solution for me

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/promo/index.php$ 
RewriteCond %{TIME} <19800705095200 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|gif|png|js|css|ttf|ico|json) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /promo/index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME} >19800705095200 [NC]
RewriteRule ^promo/index.php$ / [R=301,L,NC]
```

Thank you FoxyFish !!!!!!

PD : The cherry on the cake would be to rewrite /promo/index.php on /Countdown for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/promo/index.php$ 
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20180705095200 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /promo/index.php [R=301,L]
```

This should prevent the promo page itself being caught in the redirect.

> Edit1*

To prevent other things being caught in the redirect that you require, just use the following condition...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|gif|png|js|css|ttf|ico|json) [NC]
```

Just add or remove extensions from the list as you require them.

> Edit2*

Use the seperate condition/rule which should kick in once your promo expires.

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} >20180705095200 [NC]
RewriteRule ^promo/index.php$ / [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: It deals with the loop, thanks BUT my referenced files are now redirected too, like CSS, JS files in the head of the document :

ex : 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: Then, when the date has expired the /promo/index.php does not redirect to / with this solution.

Your update works perfectly for the "before expiration date" ! :) :) Thank you :)
The "After" is remaining ...

Comment: I also think it should work but it does not ... I tried this 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/promo/index.php$ 

    RewriteCond %{TIME} <19800705095200 [NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|gif|png|js|css|ttf|ico|json) [NC]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /promo/index.php [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{TIME} >19800705095200 [NC]
    RewriteRule /promo/index.php$ / [R=301,L]

Comment: Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to the top of your conditions. (Added into answer at *Edit1)

Comment: I edited for you (Edit 2*) ^^ (the part ">19800705095200" doesn't work... the rest is ok thanks too you)

Comment: Thank you soooooo much !!!! You saved my day :)

Can I have a little explanation of the code ? (If not it's ok because you did a lot for me but I like to understand what I do :p)

Comment: No problem :) which part of the code would you like explaining?

Comment: What really changed in the last code line ?
RewriteRule ^promo/index.php$ / [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: I replaced the `/` at the beginning with the `^` which signifies the beginning, much like the `$` meaning the end.
I also added in the `[NC]` just in case of any character case issues.

Comment: Thank you dude :)
(Sorry if it's not a correct expression for you... note sure... I'm French ^^'... But I really wanted to thank you in a cool way :p lol)

Comment: Lol, dude is fine, my friends say the same thing. No problem at all, glad to be of help.